# hide a Div if not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a plugin "product inquiry for woocommerce".
The plugin allows to ask a question about products. I would like to display the button **"ask question"** only if users are logged in.

I tried to do it whith php:

```
add_action("init", 'hide_enquiry_not_logged_in');
function hide_enquiry_not_logged_in() { 
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action( "**????I don't find the good hook????**");
    }
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __ ('Login ask question', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

But I cannot find the good hook  to work ..

Do you think of a way with CSS ? using the ID `#enquiry` ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the condition to `bbloomer_print_login_to_see()`? No need to hide or hook anything.

Comment: You can check is_user_logged_in condition before the div

Comment: Try this one  "`remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'ask_about_product_button', 30);`"

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work : 
add_action("init", 'hide_enquiry_not_logged_in');
function hide_enquiry_not_logged_in() { 
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'ask_about_product_button', 30);
    }
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __ ('Login ask question', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a check before displaying the ask question link. Try the following:

```
function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __ ('Login ask question', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
    }
}
```